# Como usar trim en una variable para mostrarla en otro campo

Tags: vue.js

En vue no me funciona el modificador trim para eliminar espacios en blancos y lo hice tal cual el tutorial. Siguen apareciendo espacios en blancos al escribir en cada campo de texto. Aquí el código

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script></head>
    <body>
        <div id="ejemplo">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre" v-model.trim="nombre">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su apellido" v-model.trim="apellido">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Ingrese su telefono" v-model.trim="telefono">
            <p>Su nombre es {{nombre}}</p>
            <p>Su apellido es {{apellido}}</p>
            <p>Su telefono es {{telefono}}</p>

        </div>

        <script src="4.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>

var ejemplo = new Vue ({
    el: "#ejemplo",
    data:{
        nombre: '',
        apellido: '',
        telefono: ''
    },
    methods: {

    }

})
```

Comment: pero ese trim es solo al leer el contenido... no cuando vos agregas caracteres.. tu idea es limpiar el contenido?

Comment: Mi idea es al ingresar el texto en el input abajo en un párrafo se replica, todo ok ahí, pero que se replique con el modificador trim eliminando espacios del input, no funciona, no elimina espacios

Comment: entonces no es asi... lo que vos estas haciendo ahi es al leer el contenido de tu variable para llenar el input, hacerle un trim... el de abajo, no esta trimeado... ahora te pongo una respuesta...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

si vos queres que

```
<p>Su nombre es {{nombre}}</p>
```

nombre aparezca sin espacios, entonces tenes dos opciones segun la [documentacion](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html)

una es hacer el trim directamente en la variable:

```
<p>Su nombre es {{nombre.trim()}}</p>
```

La otra, es usar una variable computada, para que la misma devuelva el valor como vos queres.

```
....
<p>Su nombre es {{nombresinespacios}}</p>
....
computed: {
    nombresinespacios: function () {
        return this.nombre.trim();
    }
}
```